# Quick methodology to show client a working demo

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frameworks, webforms

I am not starting an argumentative discussion here and this post is not about career development, but from the commercial point of view:
If a company was using ASP.Net MVC as a main methodology to build their web sites and application.
However, **ASP.Net MVC takes more time to show a functional application than ASP.Net Web Forms**, for example, building domain models would take some time which obviously can't be represented on a UI at that current stage.

My question is, if a client wants to see a **functional demo application** (just a proof of concept) so he knows that the company he is dealing with is professional and capable of doing that. Would it be better to do that demo in ASP.Net Web Forms only to show the client, and then work on the real application using ASP.Net MVC? If not, what are the (quick) alternatives?, I mean, **if we tell the client to wait** till we have a working demo (by ASP.Net MVC) **we may lose the client and the whole project opportunity**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebForms being faster than MVC is a myth:

1. You are not required to have a domain model, just something that represents your database tables.  This is the same in WebForms unless you are using SqlDataSource's.
2. The code in your !IsPostBack or `btnSubmit_OnSubmit` is almost identical to the `HttpPost` controller actions.  Except with MVC you don't have to write left to write `object.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text` when you understand how UpdateModel works.
3. UI is UI.  If you know HTML/CSS creating the UI is just as easy.  Almost easier in MVC because you don't have to set control properties any longer and all UI can be done in one place.

Fast MVC comes from understanding how to get the most bang from your buck using `EditorFor`, `DisplayFor` templates.  You'll need to know and understand [how to customize your Object.ascx file](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html).  With this technique under your belt you won't have to create forms by hand anymore.  2 projects ago we had a site with 100% autogenerated forms.  Change a class, change a form.  Done!

Another helpful MVC tool is the DataAnnotations attributes.  Validation made easy.  Customizing these is really easy too.  Just create your own `ModelMetaDataProvider` and starting expanding the validations your application can handle.

The only part of MVC that is slower is displaying a grid.  MVC 3 already has a useful grid tool and MVCContrib has had a grid tool out for a year now.  I ended up rolling my own, its very simple actually, loop through properties, write `<td />`'s.  < 200 lines of code.  This isn't really a benefit to WebForms either.  To use WebForms grid components means giving up a lot of quality using ObjectDataSources and the like.

To summarize fast MVC comes from these different techniques:

- Object.ascx
- ModelMetadataProviders
- UpdateModel
- DataAnnotations

If you are more advanced and know ORMS like EntityFramework and how to use Automapper your probably going to be even faster.

Answer (score 0):

I build prototypes in excel.  No logic, no code.  just basically screenshots to show the user that we are communicating the same ideas.  Create a worksheet for each "View" or screen you need to show.  Client's usually only care how "pretty" an application looks vs does it work right.

This also is a benefit as you can include more non-technical users in the prototyping process, since most are used to excel.  I can send you an example and the finished production web application, if seeing is believing.  I personally learn best by example.

And to your post where you wrote...

> I mean, if we tell the client to wait till we have a working demo (by ASP.Net MVC) we may lose the client and the whole project opportunity.

They need to have their expectations adjusted and managed.  A lot of bad development has been done quickly over the years, which makes client's ask questions like *"Bob did it in 1 hour'*.  To that I say, you can either have a lousy project fast, that you have to constantly duct tape or a well thought out and well written project that will only need to be enhanced as Bus Reqs change

Answer (score 0):

You can get a demo up and running very quickly in MVC. I could put one together much quicker than with WebForms, and I am familiar with both.

The reliance on convention in MCV will help a lot, binding is based on the names of objects.

If i was creating a quick demo, i would just create a bunch of ViewModels with static data in them, different button clicks etc will just bind one of these ViewModels to the page.

Turbo Fast!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is obvious: use whichever **you** think makes **you** faster. There's no point in using MVC if you are faster in WebForms. Especially since this is for a throw-away demo.